# how to parse CISCO IPS configuration?

Tags: networking, network-programming, firewall, cisco, network-security

I need a tool or script to parse Cisco IPS configuration,I know there is a tool called nipper for parsing firewall and switch configuration , but i doesn't support Cisco IPS , and I google it but there is no good result.

Comment: Can you give an example configuration and what you're trying to parse from it?

Comment: it's like a normal IPS configuration file , i need a tool to audit it and review the configuration against known vulnerabilities or misconfiguration issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`ciscoconfparse`](http://www.pennington.net/py/ciscoconfparse/).

The following example uses a Cisco configuration below... I can't use an IPS config unless the OP posts one... this uses a Cisco IOS configuration...

The following script will load a configuration file from `/tftpboot/bucksnort.conf` and use `CiscoConfParse.find_lines()` to parse it for the names of all serial interfaces. Note that the `^` symbol at the beginning of the search string is a regular expression; `^interface Serial` tells `python` to limit it’s search to lines that begin with `interface Serial`.

```py
[mpenning@typo tmp]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:34:23)
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
>>> parse = CiscoConfParse("/tftpboot/bucksnort.conf")
>>> serial_intfs = parse.find_lines("^interface Serial")
>>>
>>> serial_intfs
['interface Serial1/0', 'interface Serial1/1', 'interface Serial1/2']
>>>
>>> qos_intfs = parse.find_parents_w_child( "^interf", "service-policy output QOS_1" )
>>> qos_intfs
['interface Serial1/1']
```

---

```
! Filename: /tftpboot/bucksnort.conf
!
policy-map QOS_1
 class GOLD
  priority percent 10
 class SILVER
  bandwidth 30
  random-detect
 class default
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 ip address 1.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
 no cdp enable
!
interface Serial1/0
 encapsulation ppp
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface Serial1/1
 encapsulation ppp
 ip address 1.1.1.5 255.255.255.252
 service-policy output QOS_1
!
interface Serial1/2
 encapsulation hdlc
 ip address 1.1.1.9 255.255.255.252
!
class-map GOLD
 match access-group 102
class-map SILVER
 match protocol tcp
!
access-list 101 deny tcp any any eq 25 log
access-list 101 permit ip any any
!
access-list 102 permit tcp any host 1.5.2.12 eq 443
access-list 102 deny ip any any
!
logging 1.2.1.10
logging 1.2.1.11
logging 1.2.1.12
```

Comment: You could include a short example, perhaps?

Comment: it's not automated tools , it's just make it easier to review configuration , right??

Comment: @kingasmk, Audits can't be automated without knowing the requirements ahead of time, so yes you are correct... this is the scripting tool for you to build an audit script.